# Low training loss with high validation loss and low validation accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to get good accuracy with Keras (TensorFlow as the backend) using `categorical_crossentropy` for multiclass classification problem (Heart disease dataset). My model can reach good training accuracy, but the validation accuracy is low (with high validation loss). I have tried over-fitting solutions (e.g., normalization, dropout, regularization, etc.), but I still have the same problem. I have been playing around with optimizers, losses, epochs and batchsizes with no success so far. This is the code I am using:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import SGD,Adam
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.regularizers import l1,l2
# fix random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(5)
data = pd.read_csv('ProcessedClevelandData.csv',delimiter=',',header=None)
#Missing Values
Imp=SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan,strategy='mean',copy=True)
Imp=Imp.fit(data.values)
Imp.transform(data)
X = data.iloc[:, :-1].values
y=data.iloc[:,-1].values

y=to_categorical(y)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.1)
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_norm = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_norm=scaler.transform(X_test)
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(13, input_dim=13, activation='relu',use_bias=True,kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0001)))
#model.add(Dropout(0.05))
model.add(Dense(9, activation='relu',use_bias=True,kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0001)))
#model.add(Dropout(0.05))
model.add(Dense(5,activation='softmax'))
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=0.01/32, nesterov=False)
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])#adam,adadelta,
print(model.summary())
history=model.fit(X_train_norm, y_train,validation_data=(X_test_norm,y_test), epochs=1200, batch_size=32,shuffle=True)
# list all data in history
print(history.history.keys())
# summarize history for accuracy
plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
# summarize history for loss
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

And this is part of the output in which you can see the aforementioned behavior:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 13)                182       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 9)                 126       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 50        
=================================================================
Total params: 358
Trainable params: 358
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________

Train on 272 samples, validate on 31 samples
Epoch 1/1200

 32/272 [==>...........................] - ETA: 21s - loss: 1.9390 - acc: 0.1562
272/272 [==============================] - 3s 11ms/step - loss: 2.0505 - acc: 0.1434 - val_loss: 2.0875 - val_acc: 0.1613
Epoch 2/1200

 32/272 [==>...........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.6747 - acc: 0.2188
272/272 [==============================] - 0s 33us/step - loss: 1.9416 - acc: 0.1544 - val_loss: 1.9749 - val_acc: 0.1290
Epoch 3/1200

 32/272 [==>...........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.7708 - acc: 0.2812
272/272 [==============================] - 0s 37us/step - loss: 1.8493 - acc: 0.1801 - val_loss: 1.8823 - val_acc: 0.1290
Epoch 4/1200

 32/272 [==>...........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.9051 - acc: 0.2188
272/272 [==============================] - 0s 33us/step - loss: 1.7763 - acc: 0.1949 - val_loss: 1.8002 - val_acc: 0.1613
Epoch 5/1200

 32/272 [==>...........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.6337 - acc: 0.2812
272/272 [==============================] - 0s 33us/step - loss: 1.7099 - acc: 0.2426 - val_loss: 1.7284 - val_acc: 0.1935
Epoch 6/1200
....
 32/272 [==>...........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0494 - acc: 1.0000
272/272 [==============================] - 0s 37us/step - loss: 0.0532 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 4.1031 - val_acc: 0.5806
Epoch 1197/1200

 32/272 [==>...........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0462 - acc: 1.0000
272/272 [==============================] - 0s 33us/step - loss: 0.0529 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 4.1174 - val_acc: 0.5806
Epoch 1198/1200

 32/272 [==>...........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0648 - acc: 1.0000
272/272 [==============================] - 0s 37us/step - loss: 0.0533 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 4.1247 - val_acc: 0.5806
Epoch 1199/1200

 32/272 [==>...........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0610 - acc: 1.0000
272/272 [==============================] - 0s 29us/step - loss: 0.0532 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 4.1113 - val_acc: 0.5484
Epoch 1200/1200

 32/272 [==>...........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0511 - acc: 1.0000
272/272 [==============================] - 0s 29us/step - loss: 0.0529 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 4.1209 - val_acc: 0.5484
```

Comment: Do you know if you have similar distributions of your classes in your training and testing sets? In other words do each of your classes show up in roughly the same proportions in both sets?

Comment: I hope so but i am not sure. how can i do so?

Comment: You have labels for your data, correct? Count how many times each label shows up in each dataset and divide by the total number of points in each set. They don't have to be exact, but if you have no examples of a label in either dataset, that's probably bad, and if you have severely imbalanced samples that can cause challenges as well.

Answer (score 0):

A problem could be that your data is unevenly distributed in the training and testing split (as mentioned in a comment). Try to see whether the distributions are uneven and try a different seed if it is the case. 
I have had a similar problem before with a small medical dataset. The smaller the dataset the higher the likelyhood that the split datasets will not accurately represent the real distribution.

**Edit:** depending on how you set your seed you can do
`np.random.seed(my_seed)` to set it for numpy, or `random.seed(my_seed)` to set it for the python module, or to set it for keras follow [their documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development).

Comment: Just to be clear, the 'shuffle' feature in Keras's `.fit()` only shuffles the training data, not the validation set. So `np.random.shuffle(X)` and `np.random.shuffle(y)` should be a quick way... I hope!

Comment: still Not Working

Answer (score 0):

Help yourself by increasing your validation size to more like ~30%, unless you really have a large data set. Even 50/50 is often used.

Remember that **good loss and acc with bad val_loss and val_acc implies overfitting.**

Try this basic solution:

```
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau

early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',patience=10)
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1,
                              patience=6, verbose=1, mode='auto',
                              min_delta=0.0001, cooldown=0, min_lr=1e-8)

history = model.fit(X,y,num_epochs=666,callbacks=[early_stop,reduce_lr])
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Tried this one but still same results.